# C++ 2D Array Breaking During Loop Iniltialization

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm writing an object called 'Matrix'.  For parameters, the user specifies the number of rows and columns to be created.  The constructor is being called in the Main class via:

`Matrix* matrix = new Matrix(2, 3);`

The constructor is prototyped in an *.h file and is implemented in a *.cpp file as follows (with the private variables included for the sake of clarification):

```
double** arr;
int rows;
int cols;

Matrix::Matrix(int numRows, int numCols) {
    rows = numRows;
    cols = numCols;
    arr = new double*[numCols];
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        for (int x = 0; x < numCols; ++x) {
            arr[i][x] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When the program executes (compiled in Visual Studio) it builds, executes, and throws an exception similar to:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00091BCC in Matrix Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

I can only assume this means I'm not looping through the array properly as it breaks on line `arr[i][x] = 0` in the nested `for` loop.

Would anyone be able give me some tips as to why this is breaking?  How can I declare the array in a way that doesn't require one long loop being manipulated mathematically?

Thank you in advance!

**[EDIT]**

Anton provided that I need to allocate the memory to each row.  When modifying the original nested loops to the following, the program executed successfully.  Thank you!

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
    arr[i] = new double[cols];
    for (int x = 0; x < numCols; ++x) {
        arr[i][x] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to allocate memory for each row.

Comment: Similar to this?

  for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
   arr[i] = new double[cols];
   for (int x = 0; x < numCols; ++x) {
    arr[i][x] = 0;
   }
  }

Comment: @Anton You are the man.  If you create an answer, I'll give you the answer

Comment: @NickMedovich Try to avoid allocating each row separately if you care at all about efficiency. You can simply do: `double* arr = new double[numRows*numCols];`. To access the matrix at row `r`, column `c`, do: `double data = arr[r*numCols + c];`... or another way: `double* row = arr + r*numCols; double data = r[c];`

Comment: Thank you, @Ike.  I'll give that a look in a little while.  I decided to do it explicitly because my 'partner' in this project is not very familiar with programming paradigms and I figured this would be easier to explain in comments.  Otherwise I would have done so with a single array accessed programmatically.  I'll give this a go to have a look at the performance enhancements.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you might be able to explain this just as easily potentially with fewer memory blocks to deal with. You can explain it by drawing a grid and showing how the grid cell index is computed from row and column -- similar case for image processing (if you get there) accessing a pixel at a certain row/column... also less memory management stuff with just one array to allocate/free. Anyway -- cheers.

Comment: @Ike, I agree.  I'm planning on implementing it as such in the main program.  I'm only implementing it this way so my 'partner' understands a little more thoroughly.  The actual usage an access of the object will be no more difficult to understand.  When we scale up, memory will be a large problem, so I'll have to use a more efficient method, such as yours above.  Thank you very much!